# Just published Android App, Google Play not signing in

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I just published my first game a couple hours ago. I tested it by adding email accounts under "testers" and Google Play Sign in worked perfectly. However, after clicking publish on the game service, and publishing the app that was linked to the game service (leaderboards and achievements) I can no longer sign in!

What is the problem?!

**update**
If I install the app from Android Studio by running the project, I can connect. However, downloaded from the play store I am unable to connect! Did I miss some sort of licencing step or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably published a version of your app that was signed with your local debug key to the Play Store.

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#avoiding_common_setup_problems):

> You should create two client IDs, one with the release certificate fingerprint and another with the debug certificate fingerprint, and use the same package name for both. To learn more about how to specify the signing certificate in the Google Play Developer Console, see [Signing Your Applications](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: Exactly what I did! I signed and generated a release APK with a new keystore. The Google Play game services were linked to the debug.keystore, so I changed the SHA1 on the linked apps and it worked! Thank you very Much!!! App is live :)